# PHP fsocketopen - returns false when port is open

Tags: php, sockets, ip, port, fsockopen

I made this code which is supposed to show whether the program running on the specified port is running.

Now the problem is that it shows "Offline" when my port is clearly open. It however does show online for Google on port 80. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $server = '77.251.97.234';
    $port = 43594;
    $timeOut = 1;

    if ($socket = @fsockopen($server, $port, $errorNo, $errorStr, $timeOut)) {
        echo '<span style="color:green;">Online</span>';
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:red;">Offline</span>';
    }
```

Comment: For starters get rid of the `@`.  Also `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: So the port is not open. Maybe is open only internally or there is a firewall rule

Comment: Also might want to look at `$errorStr`.

Comment: The port is 100% open, people can actually access my server. And what does @ do?.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php